# Android: How to create graphs, tried using a library and ended up with a headache

Tags: android, eclipse, graph, javascript, integrate

I was wondering what the easiest way is to display a simple graph of any sort based on values that I already have. I tried using a library but ended up with more errors than i can count. What is the trick to using libraries and can someone take a second and help walk me through the steps because online all i can find is tutorials that just go: Download this jar. put it in libs and tah dah. But I am not seeming to find such luck.

Comment: It would help if you would explain, completely and precisely, what you tried and what specific problems you encountered. Focus less on complaining and focus more on giving us enough information to help you.

Comment: ok your right. So i have been trying to implement this https://github.com/jjoe64

Comment: Is there a way to download it as if it was a compelete project and then just import it? Or do you have to go through and pick out each little thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to download it as if it was a compelete project and then just import it? Or do you have to go through and pick out each little thing?

Quoting [the project documentation](http://android-graphview.org/#download):

> 1. Recommended: If you use Gradle/Android Studio you can use the library from Maven Central.
>    Add that line to your build.grade file into the dependencies block:
>
>    `compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3'`
> 2. Download .jar file and copy it into the libs folder of your project.
>    [GraphView-3.1.3.jar](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/public/GraphView-3.1.3.jar?raw=true)
> 3. Download or clone the git repository and link your project with the GraphView library project.
>    [jjoe64/GraphView on GitHub](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)

Since you have the question tagged with [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), option #2 would seem to be the most likely choice.

Note that the author also provides:

- a [series of demo projects](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos)
- [JavaDocs](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/) for the library

both of which may help you learn how to use it, as an adjunct to the rest of the documentation.